# Two TableViews One Data Source?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have setup a segue that will show a view controller with a small TableView. I want a different segue to show a bigger TableView but I want the bigger table to have the same exact info as the smaller table. Got the smaller tableView working perfect on its own, but once I give the bigger table a Data source, reset and try it out.....crashes.

// IndexPath or First Cell in TableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    if self.TaskTableViews.hidden == false {
    cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "FirstTask" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List

        cell.textLabel?.text = list.taskName
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        TaskTableViews.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.55)
        TaskTableViews.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        TaskTableViews.separatorColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(2.0) }

    if self.TaskTable2.hidden == false {
    cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "Second Task" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List
        cell.textLabel?.text = list.taskName
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        TaskTable2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.55)
        TaskTable2.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        TaskTable2.separatorColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(2.0) }

        return cell as UITableViewCell

}
```

Comment: Include the crash message you get and the stack trace

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) This is what Im getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code for your two tables is slamming into each other. To fix this, rejigger your logic. Do not make your logic depend on what is hidden. You can handle *only one table at a time*; just one table is calling here. That table comes in as the `tableView` parameter. Make your logic depend on *that*. Depending what table view that `tableView` parameter is, configure the cell and return it for that table view.

Comment: That Was It! ThankYou so much! Just had to make the IF statement be if tableView == self.TaskTabkeViews { ........} & if tableView == TaskTable2 {.....} return cell . Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider changing your approach by just resizing the table view dynamically when you go from one scene to the other instead of having two table views if the information is exactly the same.

If you're still pushing for this approach then don't make the condition be that the table view is hidden and instead implement your own logic or boolean to determine this. But again, I'd rather resize a single table view as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code

1.
var cell = UITableViewCell()
What's the point of this line?

2.
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "FirstTask" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell! 
What's the point of casting? This function returns UITableViewCell (not even optional)

3.
cell.textLabel?.text = list.taskName
Should not compile, cause UITableViewCell doesn't have textLabel

4.
TaskTableViews.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.55)
What's the point of doing this every cell request? Move this to viewDidLoad or other appropriate place

5. Your if { } parts are identical except of reuse identifier
6. Use tableView argument when needed
7. Use if { } else

8.
return cell as UITableViewCell
Why cast? Just return

I'm sure I haven't found all of them))